# how to find address in memory using ADRP and ADD (ARM64) instructions?

Tags: disassembly, arm64

[image]

This part of the disassembler code takes the symbol "1" from memory to change i I need to know what address is assigned to the "x1" register, but the debugger does not work for me.

I have little experience in reverse engineering so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hello, it's you again :)) It seems that you found the location of that `N` variable in the last post. If I calculated correctly, the address in x1 is `0x4151250`. Good luck!

Comment: yes it's me haha. I changed the instructions a bit. Very strange, there is no address 0x4151250 in the code

Comment: It seems to me that something is wrong with my disassembler, I studied ARDP instructions, you specified the address correctly

Comment: No, I think your disassembler might not wrong. You might need to (somehow) rebase the program, because the address shown in the disassembler might **not** be the same as the address of the program when it executes on your device. But I think rebase needs debugger. How did you manage to run the debugger before it fails to start?

Comment: The problem is that I am parsing an IOS application, the debugger is not working, most likely due to the fact that this application cannot be run on the computer

Have you had experience debugging iOS applications?

Comment: No. In fact, I have never got an Iphone. Do you have a Mac? You can might be able to debug the app from your phone using Xcode. Just do some Google Search. Or if you have Jailbroken iPhone, you can install gdb on it (plenty tutorials on the internet) to debug. You can also try iOS emulator on Xcode, but I don't know if it works or not

Comment: yes i have a jailbroken device, i will try to install gdb